# Clone Database into Different Name in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

Hi I am new to Laravel.

In our project ,we have to clone the current database into same server with different name.For example if our current database name is "test" means , I have to clone the database(test) into same server with different name like "test_2018" and I need all the tables in database(test) to our clone database(test_2018).

How can I achieve this in Laravel programmatically and I have used laravel version 5.0.

Comment: do you need to migrate data as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sumit.Yes , whatever in the database (test) will be same in clone database ( test_2018).

Comment: and why you want to do it  programmatically?

Comment: As of now , we reset the database( truncate all table programmatically ) for every year and we lost the previous year data.Now we have to maintain the previous year data with different database name.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using a MySql database.

You can create a batch file, then calling the file using the task scheduler in Laravel.
inside your Laravel project in the `App\Console\Kernel.php` file, add this line to the schedule function to run the command every year.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->exec('/batch.bat')->yearly();
    }
```

You need to create a scheduled task using the task scheduler if you have Windows, and if you have Linux (90% you have Linux especially if your project is running on the hosting server), then you should create a CRON job and place this script inside your script(according to Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling)):

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then create a batch.bat(Windows) or batch.sh(Linux) file inside your project folder, and place this content inside it:

```
mysql -u [USER-NAME] -p[PASSWORD] [YOUR-CURRENT-DATABASE-NAME] > /dumpfile.sql
CREATE DATABASE [NEW-DATABASE-NAME];
[NEW-DATABASE-NAME] < /dumpfile.sql
```

Don't wait and test it manually right away using the command:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```